# Named Query Possibility

Tags: java, jpa

I have a fields of customerName, MembershipNumber, nationality and some other field in my customer table and if i get one value from the above three. I need to write only one named query to get the value from the Customer table from the value i got. Is there any possibility to do that by named query without use of normal query in jpa?...

```
 StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder();
 s.append("select c from customerdetail c where )
 if(customerName!=null)
 {
   s.append(" c.customerName = :customerName")
 }
else if(memberShipNumber!=null)
 {
   s.append(" c.memberShipNumber = :memberShipNumber")
 }
else if(nationality!=null)
 {
   s.append(" nationality = :nationality)
 }
```

Here i use the same table with three conditions. So is there any possiblity to write only one named query or any other static query to satisfy all the three conditions in jpa?

Comment: Can you add more information like - current query, problem faced & expected result of it.

Comment: What? Can you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading [ObjectDB's manual on JPA Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select). It provides information on selecting JPA entities and different variations with its custom fields. It has query examples expressed as in JPQL so with use of Criteria. And yes, you can define namedQuery using JPQL and later use-re-use it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i need the query to be executed on static time. so any possibility for doing that?...

Answer (score 1):

Named queries are static & their scope is persistence context, they can't be altered at runtime.

Below is the sample for adding parameter based on condition using Criteria API.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomerDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(CustomerDetail.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<CustomerDetail> CustomerDetail_ = m.entity(CustomerDetail.class);
Root<CustomerDetail> detail = cq.from(CustomerDetail.class);

if(customerName != null)
cq.where(cb.equal(detail.get(CustomerDetail_.customerName), customerName));

if(memberShipNumber != null)
cq.where(cb.equal(detail.get(CustomerDetail_.memberShipNumber), memberShipNumber));

if(nationality != null)
cq.where(cb.equal(detail.get(CustomerDetail_.nationality), nationality));

cq.select(detail);
TypedQuery<CustomerDetail> q = em.createQuery(cq);
List<CustomerDetail> customerList= q.getResultList();
```

Else, you can go with building a query with string by appending conditions, instead of named query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use projection with NamedQuery, this example will obtain a single customerName field if MembershipNumber is unique or a List with every customerName that matches the where condition:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="getCustomerName", query="SELECT c.customerName FROM Customer c WHERE c.membershipNumber = :memNum")
public class Customer {
...
}
```

Then you can call it with: (em is your EntityManager)

```
String customerName = em.createNamedQuery("getCustomerName")
.setParameter("memNum", myMembershipNumber)
.getSingleResult();
```